# React Native TouchableHighlight : get component and context

Tags: react-native

I want on an onPress in a TouchableHighlight to get both props from the component, and get the global this context.

I can get both separately using:

```
 onPress={this.alertProp} // get props from TouchableHighlight using this.myProp
```

Or

```
onPress={() => this.alertProp()} // get global this to use e.g. this.state
```

Any simple way to get both?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get props from a child component, you can just use a `ref`.  E.g.:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {

  alertProp(index) {
    //now "this" has your global component,
    //and this._touchables[index] is the ref
    //of your TouchableHighlight
  }

  render() {
    const data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    return (
     <View>
      {data.map((item, index) => {
       return (
         <TouchableHighlight
          onPress={() => this.alertProp.bind(this)(index)}
          ref={(t) => this._touchables[index] = t}
         />;
        );
      }}
    </View>
   );
    
  }
}
```

If I understand your question correctly, this gives your `alertProp` function access to both global (component) state and the props of your child `TouchableHighlight` component.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I forgot to say I have a lot of TouchableHighlight generated by a loop, so can't use a static reference.

Comment: The `ref` prop takes a callback for that very reason.  You can use the callback to assign your child components to an object in the parent, and access them by passing the index of the pressed `TouchableHighlight` in your `onPress` function.  I've updated the snippet above with a minimal example.

Comment: Seems perfect on the paper, didn't know the use of ref as a function. Let me test it and I'll accept the answer if it's working :-)

Comment: At the end I had trouble with variable ref that wasn't set always properly inside the loop (just the last index was not null). I found another way to do it, posting the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, with binding more parameters I'm able to make it work.

```
class Example extends React.Component {



alertProp(param1, param2) {
    //now "this" has your global component,
    //param1, param2 don't get rewrited if they are dynamic inside a loop
  }

  render() {
    const data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    var param1;
    return (
     <View>
      {data.map((item, index) => {
       param1 = index;
       return (
         <TouchableHighlight
          onPress={this.alertProp.bind(this,param1, param2)}
         />;
        );
      }}
    </View>
   );

  }
}
```

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working!  I suppose it's more efficient to `bind` the index like that, anyway, rather than creating a whole new function. :)